# std::_USE not defined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

We have some code using the class CStdString, which is a wrapper for std::string, in a version from January 2005.

This class uses a macro SS_USE_FACET to encapsulate the function std::use_facet with a special implementation for Microsoft C++. For the Microsoft compiler it uses an alternative macro _USE.

We are now getting an error, that "_USE is not a member of std".

If I comment out the Microsoft specific case in this macro, it compiles fine. This is the macro definition, with the Microsoft version commented out.

```
#if defined(__SGI_STL_PORT) && (__SGI_STL_PORT >= 0x400 )

    #if defined(__STL_NO_EXPLICIT_FUNCTION_TMPL_ARGS) && defined(_MSC_VER)
        #ifdef SS_ANSI
            #pragma schMSG(__STL_NO_EXPLICIT_FUNCTION_TMPL_ARGS defined!!)
        #endif
    #endif
    #define SS_USE_FACET(loc, fac) std::use_facet<fac >(loc)

//#elif defined(_MSC_VER )

//  #define SS_USE_FACET(loc, fac) std::_USE(loc, fac)

// ...and
#elif defined(_RWSTD_NO_TEMPLATE_ON_RETURN_TYPE)

      #define SS_USE_FACET(loc, fac) std::use_facet(loc, (fac*)0)

#else

    #define SS_USE_FACET(loc, fac) std::use_facet<fac >(loc)

#endif
```

Is this OK?

Can I assume that Microsoft have adopted the standard implementation and finally removed the special macro _USE?

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2017, but I think the problem must have started in a very recent update. I am not actually getting the error on my development PC, but there are two outstanding updates which I have not applied (15.7.2 and 15.7.3). A colleague is getting the error, and he may have installed 15.7.2. I will try it out later (but Visual Studio updates can be time consuming).

Comment: I have updated to 15.7.3 and I am getting the same error as my colleague. (error C2039: '_USE': is not a member of 'std').

Comment: In VS2015 the macro `_USE` is just a `#define` for `use_facet`. Not unlikely that this has been removed in a resent cleanup, now that the latest VS2017 [claims standard conformance](https://isocpp.org/blog/2018/05/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-cpp-standard-bat-ulzii-luvsanbat).

Comment: Is there any reason to assume a 13 year old work-around is still needed? I'm wondering why you don't just drop it, given that it now compiles without `_USE`.

Comment: I agree, and I have dropped it, but I'm not really familiar with the function (which is my failing) and I haven't tested it, both of which would be reasons not to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution (commenting out the MS specific lines and falling back to the standard `std::use_facet<fac>(loc)`) is correct.

This is confirmed by a Microsoft engineer at the bottom of [this page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/263793/msvc-141426428-xlocale-missing-use-macro.html#reply-265857):

> Yes, this non-Standard macro was intentionally removed.
>
> [...]
>
> You should replace such calls with std::use_facet(loc)